# grep and print all pattern in one lane

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a file with a list of pattern like this

```
K00001

K00003

K00005
```

I want to grep and print my pattern in a tab delimited table (the original table is without blank line) like this:

```
K00001  ko00010_Glycolysis__Gluconeogenesis

K00003  ko00010_Glycolysis__Gluconeogenesis

K00005  ko00010_Glycolysis__Gluconeogenesis

K00001  ko00020_Citrate_cycle_(TCA_cycle)

K00003  ko00020_Citrate_cycle_(TCA_cycle)

K00005  ko00020_Citrate_cycle_(TCA_cycle)
```

to obtain this: one line with all the pattern that are in my patterns' file

```
K00001_ko00010_Glycolysis__Gluconeogenesis;K00001_ko00020_Citrate_cycle_(TCA_cycle)
K00003_ko00010_Glycolysis__Gluconeogenesis;K00003_ko00020_Citrate_cycle_(TCA_cycle)
K00005_ko00010_Glycolysis__Gluconeogenesis;K00005_ko00020_Citrate_cycle_(TCA_cycle)
```

Comment: Are you required to use grep? This would be easier with sed or awk.

Comment: Are there blank lines in the pattern file?

Comment: Hi, mark no there aren't blank lines in the file

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/). We'll pass both filenames as arguments, and use the `if (FNR == NR)` idiom to do something different depending on whether we're reading the first or second file. We'll use *associative arrays* to store the keys and the output lines.

This is the file `a.awk`:

```
# usage: awk -f a.awk keyfile1 datafile2
BEGIN {
    FS = "\t"                               # set field separator to TAB
}
{
    if (FNR == NR) {                        # if looking at first (key) file
        k[$1]=$1                            # just save each key
    } else {                                # if looking at second file
        if ($1 in k) {                      # if first col is one that we want
            output=$1 "_" $2                # prepare output line
            if (out[$1]=="")                # if first time we've seen this key
                out[$1]=output              # store output as is
            else                            # and when we find more matches for this key
                out[$1]=out[$1] ";" output  # we append ";" and the output
        }
    }
}
END {                                       # at the end
    for (i in out)                          # print all the output lines
        print out[i]
}
```

And here is how to use it:

```
$ awk -f a.awk file1 file2
K00001_ko00010_Glycolysis__Gluconeogenesis;K00001_ko00020_Citrate_cycle_(TCA_cycle)
K00003_ko00010_Glycolysis__Gluconeogenesis;K00003_ko00020_Citrate_cycle_(TCA_cycle)
K00005_ko00010_Glycolysis__Gluconeogenesis;K00005_ko00020_Citrate_cycle_(TCA_cycle)
```

Comment: HI mark is there  the possibility also to print a blank line if one more pattern are not found in file2??

Comment: @IlarioFerrocino I'm not totally sure what you mean. But, if you want a blank line for every pattern in file1 that is not matched at all in file2, change `for (i in out)` to `for (i in k)`. This loops through all the keys rather than all the matched lines. So if you have key `K00002` in file1 but not in file2, `out["K00002"]` will be `""` (since it was never set) and an empty line will be printed. Is that what you need?